# youtube-dl: Run PowerShell function through --exec

Tags: powershell, youtube-dl

I have created a PowerShell script to download videos using youtube-dl. When a video is successfully downloaded I want to copy its `.info.json` file, and append it into a script file I am using as a database. youtube-dl provides the `--exec` parameter, which allows you to run a command when a video is successfully downloaded. This is my script:

```
Write-Host "Checking for updates to youtube-dl . . . "
.\youtube-dl.exe -U
Write-Host "Searching for and downloading videos . . . "
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'UTF8'
if (![System.IO.File]::Exists('.\database.js')) {
    Set-Content -Path .\database.js -Value "const database = [
]"
}
$stopWatch = [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::startNew()
.\youtube-dl.exe --config-location config.txt --write-info-json --exec "Write-MetadataToDatabase {}" # Call the Write-MetadataToDatabase function, passing the location of the video .info.json file as {}
$elapsed = $stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
Write-Host "Finished downloading. Took $elapsed."
Read-Host -Prompt "Done, press Enter to exit"

function Write-MetadataToDatabase {
    Param($Path)
    $content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($Path, [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8) | ConvertFrom-Json
    $content.PSObject.Properties.Remove('formats')
    $content = $content | ConvertTo-Json -compress

    $stream = [IO.File]::OpenWrite('.\database.js')
    $stream.SetLength($stream.Length - 4)
    $stream.Close()
    $stream.Dispose()

    $content + ",
]" | Add-Content .\database.js -Encoding UTF8
    $i++
    Write-Host "Appended video metadata to database file"
}
```

How can run my function, passing the location of the video's `.info.json` file when a video is successfully downloaded?

**Edit**
I've figured out how to get the location of the `.info.json` file. Passing {} as a parameter for `--exec` returns the location of the video, which is the same location as the metadata files. I still cannot figure out how to invoke my function successfully.

Comment: Can you give us an idea whats in your `config.txt` file?  We need something that will reproduce on our end to help you test it :)

Comment: config.txt here: https://pastebin.com/VjPjWGHb

Comment: I can't get a `.json` file to be created every time, do you have a workaround to force a .json file to be made?

Comment: My current script does not require a workaround to write the json, it just creates one every time with the set parameters.

Comment: When I run your code with the newest youtube-dl version, sometimes a .js file is made, sometimes not.  It could be something on youtube's side, for instance maybe .json files only exist on certain sorts of videos or videos uploaded at a certain resolution.   Or maybe the videos you use always will have a .json file.  This is just a warning.

Comment: Can you provide an example of say a particular video that youtube-dl does not create a json file for? I'm not sure what parts of my code you are running as the code I provided to SO should not work.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the `--Exec` param to work, but here's an approach which should get you started.

```
$files = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avWtg18HMbQ"
forEach ($file in $files){
    & '.\youtube-dl.exe' "$($file) --write-info-json -i -f bestvideo+bestaudio/best"
    $elapsed = $stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")

    Write-Host "Finished downloading. Took $elapsed."

    #find most recent file
    $thisJSONFile = Get-ChildItem *.json | Sort-Object -Descending Created | Select-Object -First 1 | Get-Content | ConvertFrom-Json



    Write-Output "The most recent file was $($thisJSONFile._filename) which had $($thisJSONFile.view_count) views"

    #do other things with properties of $thisJSONFile here
}
```

Which would give this output

```
The most recent file was [No Damage_Ichimonji] SEVEN ASHINA SPEARS Shikibu Toshikatsu Yamauchi Mini-Boss Fight _ Sekiro-DdMUG3PvWII.mp4 which had 16 views
```

You could add your own logic to the end of the script block to do whatever you'd like with the .JSON files which are downloaded, I hope this helps.